# How to set a readwrite internal, readonly external property in protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I have some classes have same behaviors, they all have

properties > `savedPath: String`, `items: [String]`, `currentItem: [String]`

functions > `archive(with items: [String])`, `unarchive()`

So I create a protocol.swift and let those classes conform this protocol to implement these common behavior.But, in my case, i want:

1. `items` is a readonly external, readwrite internal
2. `archive/unarchive` are private func

i tried to use `private(set)` before `items`, `private` before `archive/unarchive` and some errors showed up.
Is there any flexible solutions to fix that?

before without protocol

```swift
class SampleClass {
    private(set) var items: [SampleModel] {
        set {
            archive(with: newValue)
        } get {
            return unarchive()
        }
    }

    func archive(with addresses: [SampleModel]) { ... }
    func unarchive() -> [SampleModel] { ... }
}
```

after try to use protocol to satisfy

```swift
protocol SampleProtocol {
    associatedtype Item: Switchable

    var savedPath: String { get }
    var items: [Item] { get }
    var currentItem: Item? { get }

    func archive(with items: [Item])
    func unarchive() -> [Item]
}
```

Comment: Don't put anything private into protocols. Follow that rule and you should be okay. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must remove any private function from protocol (Since it's meaningless). Nothing is private inside a protocol( setter or function or etc. )

```
protocol SampleProtocol {
    associatedtype Item: Switchable

    var savedPath: String { get }
    var items: [Item] { get }
    var currentItem: Item? { get }
}
```

And you should then implement the class access controls like this:

```
class SampleClass {
    private(set) var items: [SampleModel] {
        set {
            archive(with: newValue)
        } get {
            return unarchive()
        }
    }

    private func archive(with addresses: [SampleModel]) { /* ... */ }
    private func unarchive() -> [SampleModel] { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: solved and thx, after remove private from protocol, the private(set) is ok in classes.

Comment: so is there a workaround to avoid repeating write `archive(items: [Item])` and `unarchive -> [Item]` in different classes. the `items` in different classes are all conform to `Item` but are different concrete types

Comment: Yes that would be cool too. Please don't forget to accept answer if you find this useful.